# Calculating $G/X$ and $G/Y$ when $G$ is cyclic group of order $10$ and $a$ is the generator of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across the following question:

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $10,$ where $a$ is the generator of $G$. Let $X=\langle a^2\rangle$ and $Y=\langle a^5\rangle$. Calculate the left cosets in $G$ of $X$ and $Y$.

As I understand, we need to calculate $G/X$ and $G/Y$. First, we know that $|G|=|\langle a\rangle|=10$. If we take a look at $G/X$ then we need to find

$$ G/X = \{gX\,:\,g\in G \} = \{g\langle a^2 \rangle \,:\,g\in G \}.$$

But how do I continue from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that $X=\{e,a^2,a^4,a^6,a^8\}$. That means $G/X$ has only two cosets. One of them must be $X$ itself, and we have no choice-the second coset must contain all the remaining elements of $G$ so it is $\{a,a^3,a^5,a^7,a^9\}$.

Then note that $Y=\{e,a^5\}$. So $G/Y$ contains $5$ cosets. Well, it is really easy to find them. Just take an element $g\in G$ and start multiplying it by elements from $Y$ to get the coset $gY$. Then take an element which is not in $gY$ and find its coset. And continue that way. Your group is very small so it is easy. So we get the cosets are $\{e,a^5\},\{a,a^6\},\{a^2,a^7\},\{a^3,a^8\},\{a^4,a^9\}$.